# Objective-C How to copy an objects iVars from one object to another

Tags: objective-c, copy, copy-constructor

Similar to a copy constructor - 
I need to retain the same pointer to the original object - because it is referenced in a data structure  - but I would like to assign its values from another object.

How is this done?

For instance a contrived example using an array to store the objects - but in reality I might not have access to the data structure containing my object

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *someNumber;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *someInternalValues;
@end


@interface AnotherClass

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *array; // array of MyClass objects
@end

@implementation AnotherClass

-(void)createArrayOfMyClassObjects
{
  MyClass *object1 = [MyClass new];
  MyClass *object2 = [MyClass new];

  //initialize the object1 and object2

  // add them to my array or any other data structure that it may be
  [self.array addObjects:@[object1,object2]];
}

-(void)copyThisObjectData:(MyClass *object) 
{
  // here would like to do look up my object in array corresponding to "object"
  MyClass *myObject = .../// found it somehow

 // and here copy its values
  myObject = object; // don't want "object" pointer , I want to copy its data to MyObject that is in the array (or could be contained by someone else)
}
```

Comment: have you tried `myObject = [object copy]` ?

Comment: You should implement NSCopying protocol and override copyWithZone: method.

Comment: The simplest approach is to simply write a method that copies from one to the other, field-by-field.  This ideally would be an instance method of the same class and would either create the target object or accept it as a parameter.  The standardized name for a method that does this is `copy`.

Comment: Of course, one thing you'd need to do is decide how "deep" the copy operation should be.  In the case of an embedded NSArray, you could simply copy the array pointer, create a new copy of the array, using the same objects that were in the old one, or create a new copy of the array, making copies of the objects within.  (And it can go "deeper" still, if you wish.)

Comment: calling copy would create a new object whose contents are initialized to the copied object. That isn't what I want. I want the same object (pointer) with the contents of the "copied" object. It would need to be similar to the implementation of NSCopy (actually the same implementation...) should I just create this method?